# Trying to avoid "spaghetti code", why is multiple if-else bad?

Tags: php, coding-style

I was just reading the [top 100 signs of spaghetti code](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/2884-4-30.htm) and I came across number 4, which simply states:

```
if ($status == "awake"){ 
    $actitivity = "Writing spaghetti code"; 
} else if ($healthstatus == "OK"){ 
    $activity = "Sleep"; 
} else { 
    print "CALL 911 IMMEDIATELY!"; 
}
```

I've seen this multiple if-else pattern in [other spaghetti discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195520/what-is-spaghetti-code#198276).  I'm a little confused why this is, and even if it's applicable to this example.

Is the above example bad because

- the first variable is `actitivity` which indicates the coder needs some sleep, so it's a joke, or
- view shouldn't be being output during logic, or
- something about too many if/else

---

*EDIT* never mind this second part, it's bad because of nested conditionals and multiple returns

<s>In the [other spaghetti discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195520/what-is-spaghetti-code#198276) link, is it bad because</s>

<s>- the logic has `return` in it, which breaks the flow, or</s>

<s>- there's too many `if/else` piled on top of eachother...?</s>

Comment: Ultimately, most of it can be boiled down to formal computer science under the banner of [Cyclomatic Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity).

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the link! That's a pretty clear model of what everybody was trying to describe. More nodes or changes -> more complexity -> more difficult to read -> spaghetti.

Comment: yep, that's it. But it's not just difficult to read, it's also difficult to predict. Maintenance and testing of a code block becomes exponentially harder with every additional node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`If/else` statement often breaks [Open-closed principle](http://www.oodesign.com/open-close-principle.html).  (Java example but valid in PHP too)

Solution => favor polymorphism.

Besides, assigning a temporary variables more than once is really error prone and reduces readability. Especially in PHP since it isn't a static-typed language. 
Indeed, what if someone first assign `$actitivity = "Writing spaghetti code";` and then `$actitivity = 1;` ?? ...blending apples with oranges inside the same container.. Look at this: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/split-temporary-variable

Also, the logic allows for side-effect (`print`) only if one of the condition is verified => Method isn't cohesive and thus SRP violated.

Comment: For people like myself: `SRP states that every object should have a single responsibility, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class`.

Comment: SRP also applies to method .. not only the whole object itself. How would you name a method that does print in one case and do other things in others case: `printPerhaps`? .. tend to make your method having a high cohesion is one of the best way to have a clean code. In this case, splitting the method.

Comment: For more information, look at this: http://codebork.com/2011/02/02/revisiting-solid-principles-srp-methods.html.  There is one error in the second image's presented (since identical to the first one), but in the github associated, there's the good sample :)