# If sheet exist, don't add another one

Tags: excel, vba

If the sheet "Data" does not exist, the code works perfectly, if it does exist however I get the error "Name already exists, try a different name". I've simply fixed this with an `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler`, the problem however is that after the code runs and the macro triggers the errorhandler msgbox , it still creates a new sheet regardless (with the names 'Sheet1,2,3,...').

Snippet:

```
Sub AddWorkSheet()
    Dim wb As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Sheets.Add.Name = ("Data")
    Set shtDest = Sheets("Data")

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox ("Something went wrong."), vbCritical

End Sub
```

I'd like the code to simply return the message box and not create any additional sheets if the sheet "Data" already exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test or check if sheet exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists)

Answer (score 1):

Before adding a sheet, check if it exists:

```
Function ShtExist(ShtName As String) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
    ShtExist = Len(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ShtName).Name) > 0
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub AddWorkSheet()

    Dim wb As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet
    If ShtExist("Data") Then
    MsgBox ("Something went wrong."), vbCritical
    Else
    Sheets.Add.Name = ("Data")
    Set shtDest = Sheets("Data")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to assign a non-exist worksheet to a variable, VBA will return error 9. From my POV, I think it's useful to trap that error and then create the worksheet if needed.

So I would use:

```
Sub AddWorkSheet()
Dim wb As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Set shtDest = Sheets("Data")


'<--rest of your code-->
'
'
'
'
'
'
''<--rest of your code-->

Set shtDest = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing

Exit Sub


ErrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 9 Then
    'must create worksheet DATA
    Sheets.Add.Name = ("Data")
    Set shtDest = Sheets("Data")
    Resume Next
Else
    'different error. MSgbox with new error
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Number
    Stop
End If
End Sub
```

Please, note that right before the `ErrorHanlder` part, I added `Exit Sub` to avoid this part of code being executed every time the sub runs.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work though. I still get the same error (1004, via the else function in the errorhandler), but right after that another numbered sheet gets created.

Comment: You get error 1004 in line `MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Number`?

Answer (score 0):

(**EDIT:** A previous version of this answer produced the wrong result, details in comments.)

This should work. Note the use of `On Error Resume Next` combined with `On Error GoTo 0` instead of `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler`. (GoTo statements are commonly associated with [so-called "spaghetti code"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195520/what-is-spaghetti-code#325789), so it could be a good habit to avoid them when possible.)

```
Sub AddWorkSheet()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
    If Err.Number <> 9 Then ' 9 means subscript out of range
        MsgBox ("Sheet already exists."), vbCritical
    Else
        Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = "data"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

In your original code, you could add an `Exit Sub` statement before the error handler; without it `ErrorHandler` will always be called. (You might want to have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Sheets.Add).).

Comment: I hardly recommend to read: [What's the deference between “end” and “exit sub” in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491908/whats-the-deference-between-end-and-exit-sub-in-vba). `End` will kill your whole VBA execution. • And your code will still add a sheet even if sheet `data` exists.

Comment: Indeed, that was sloppy of me, I've edited accordingly. Thanks for the correction. (As for `End` vs. `Exit Sub`, I'm perfctly aware of the difference, that's irrelevant after the edit, but the choice should obviously be made depending on context.)

Comment: It will fail if eg a chart sheet named `Data` exists because you check only for existing worksheets. Note that `Sheets <> Worksheets`. `Sheets` can contain all type of sheets like `Charts`, `Worksheets`, etc.

Comment: Thanks again, good point. Always learning. I'll leave the post as is for now.