# Creating a variable or a data type again and again in a loop or using the datatype initialised before that loop

Tags: c++, loops, memory, input

which is better
creating a variable/datatype in a loop?
or
creating the same outside the loop

```
int a = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
    cin >> a;
}

//or 

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
    int a;
    cin >> a;

}
```

Which is the better way and why?

Comment: Always the second way. Don't leak scope unnecessarily. Trust the compiler to optimise the code.

Comment: write code to express intent. Do you need `a` to be declared outside of the loop? If no, it should not be declared outside of the loop. If you worry about performance, then profile and measure, most likely you will find that there is zero difference after compiler optimizations

Comment: Also you probably don't want to name your variable `a`. Use a more descriptive name and avoid needing to write a comment that tells the person reading the code the purpose of the variable.

Comment: Contrary to what beginners believe, variables - particularly of primitive types - are dirt cheap. Limiting their scope is an effective way of avoiding difficult bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a code style question when you are use a [fundamental data type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), like int.

Most of modern compilers will generate same machine code for both type of loops, where local variable have fundamental data type.

Some style guides recommending delay variable declaration as much as possible, to make code more human readable and avoid cognitive brain overload. So you don't need to scroll up/down the code to understand logic it implements. It is also considered not to create huge loops bodies, split code on small chunks  1-15 lines and extract them on well named functions, because of the same reason I.e. something like:

```
static int read_int_from_console() {
  int ret = 0;
  std::scanf("%d", i);
  return ret;
}

int input[3] = {0};
for(std::size_t i=0; i < 3; i++) {
  input[i] = read_int_from_console();
}
```

Program are for humans, not for computers. If code compiles, it doesn't mean it works correctly and you or someone else can understand it and fix issues or change this logic during maintenance. So ty to write your code with expectation that someone else will read it. Maybe it will be your self a decade after and need to rummage about [spaghetti code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195520/what-is-spaghetti-code).

Another style guides sayin - not to create any variables inside loop body, because programmers considered to make resource leaks (i.e. memory leaks, unclosed file descriptors etc) more likely inside such loop bodies, so that you've initialized a resource and forgot to free it. i.e. something like:

```
 for(int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
   const float* hidden_outputs = new float [2500];
   const float* hidden_errors = new float [2500];
   ...
   correct_errors(who, outputs_errors, final_outputs, hidden_outputs );
   correct_errors(wih, hidden_errors, hidden_outputs, input);              
   ...
   // expected but missed     
   // delete [] hidden_outputs; 
   // delete [] hidden_errors;
 }
```

In any case. When you are working with complex data types, i.e. arrays, structures, classes etc. second approach leads to un effective program (general case off cause, because sometimes your logic need this initialization). Such code will use more memory and CPU time at the same time, since initialization and destruction happens each loop iteration.

[Google C++ style guide local variables](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Local_Variables) have good explanations.

> There is one caveat: if the variable is an object, its constructor is invoked every time it enters scope and is created, and its destructor is invoked every time it goes out of scope
>
> ```
> // Inefficient implementation:
> for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
>   Foo f;  // My ctor and dtor get called 1000 times each.
>   f.DoSomething(i);
> }
> ```
>
> It may be more efficient to declare such a variable used in a loop
> outside that loop:
>
> ```
> Foo f;  // My ctor and dtor get called once each.
> for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
>   f.DoSomething(i);
> }
> ```

P.S. More programming code style guides can be found in books like, Robert C. Martin Clean Code , Martin Fowler Refactoring, Scott Meyers Effective C++/Effective STL/Effective Modern C++/ etc.

See also [Coding standards FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards)

Comment: `(int i = 0; i < 1000000` is vulnerable to `int` overflow on some platforms. For a comprehensive answer such as this, you ought to fix.

Comment: Tell Google to do the same in theirs style guide :) It is considered in most now days rachs it is 4 byte i.e. `[ -2147483648-2147483647]`. If you still using Turbo/Borland C++ 3.1 where int it 2 byte, my condolences. You'd better switch to Linux/GCC/Code::Blocks it is free.

Comment: My hypothesis that there are more chips out there running C++ code with 16 bit `int` than any other size stills sands. There is no point in deliberately writing non-portable code.

Comment: I tried to correct the quote formatting by using quoting also for the code, I hope I didnt mess it up

Comment: you suggest to compare the assembly, but it isnt 100% identical for the two functions, eg here: https://godbolt.org/z/dc4s55q5d

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thanks for formatting. 2. Machine code actually same, sequence of  3  `mov -> xor -> lea rsi, QWORD PTR [rsp] -> call` commands. Optimizer removed loop, and call `scanf` function 3 times to the same memory address.

Comment: not a style thing at all for ints. If needed outside the scope it must be declared outside. Otherwise dont pollute your namespace

Comment: it might be equivalent but it isnt identical. Imho discussing the machine code and explaining that it is the same would bring more than discussing guidelines

Comment: @Bathsheba & 463035818_is_not_a_number in any case, thanks for your help and comments. I've edit my post to make it more generic.